# Using color in a self defined command causes an unexpected indent

Tags: macros, color, indentation

Today i came across a strange issue when using color in a self defined command with one optional argument. When i use the command with the optional argument an indent happens for the following paragraph while no indent appears when not using an argument.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\heading}[1][]{%
    {\color{blue}B\\}%
    % {B\\}%
}%

\begin{document}
\heading[ABCD]
Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend.

\heading
Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend. Hello Darkness my old friend.
\end{document}
```

When line 5 (`{\color{blue}B\\}`) is used the resulting document looks like this:
[image: Using color in the command causes a indent]

When using line 6 (`{B\\}`) the indent does not happen:
[image: No indent is happening when not using a color]

Based on my research this happens regardless of using `color` or `xcolor`.
Now i am wondering why this is happening in the first place (is it a bug?) and how to fix this behavior.

Comment: Add `\ignorespaces` at the end of your `\heading` command

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your fast response, it now works as expected. Could you also explain why that happens in the first place?

Comment: You are adding a space after the heading, instead of ignorespaces you could do `\heading[ABCD]Hello Darkness` with no space before Hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you see can be narrowed down to

```latex
B\\ Hello

B\\\write-1{} Hello
```

the difference between the two lines being the `\write-1{}`. Which can be dissected even further to

```latex
B\nobreak\hfil\break
          \space Hello

B\nobreak\hfil\break
\write-1{}\space Hello
```

The above will make two very similar horizontal lists (a chunk of text that TeX hasn't yet broken into lines to make a paragraph).  When TeX breaks the first horizontal list into lines, the `\nobreak\hfil` will fill the rest of the `B` line with blank space, and the `\break` will force a line break at that point.  The `\space` will then be discarded because it happens at the beginning of the line, and `Hello` will be typeset flush with the left margin.

The difference in the second horizontal list is that it contains a `\write`, which adds a “whatsit” node at that point, which occurs at the beginning of the line, since it was broken by `\break`.  The `\space` that follows is not discarded, because it happens in the middle of the line.

In your case, the “whatsit” is not a `\write`, but a `\special`, which is inserted there because the scope of the current colour ends and the `color` package uses that `\special` to revert back to the previous colour.

---

To work around that, you can either add `\ignorespaces` to your macro, so that blank spaces will be ignored:

```latex
\newcommand{\heading}[1][]{%
  {\color{blue}B\\}%
  \ignorespaces
}%
```

or you can use instead `\textcolor{blue}{B}`, so that instead of inserting the whatsit in the beginning of the next line, it will be inserted right after `B` and won't disturb your horizontal list.  Or even better, use both:

```latex
\newcommand{\heading}[1][]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{B}\\%
  \ignorespaces
}%
```